# How to Fetch all chats from firebase

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

Hi unable to fetch all my previous chats from firebase i have tried as below but its getting nothing.

My Firebase messages format like below.

[Firebase messages format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdeI8.png)

And the code i have written for fetching chats as below.

```
  let messagesRef = Database.database().reference().child("chat_messagesid")
    let queryRef = messagesRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "senderId").queryEqual(toValue: Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)

    queryRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in

        let msgDict = snapshot.value as! [String: Any]
        let msg = msgDict["text"] as! String

        self.messagesArray = [] //erases the array
        self.messagesArray.append(msg) //adds this new message at index 0

        print(self.messagesArray) //print is just for example
        //normally call tableView.reloadData() which will refresh
        //  the cells in the tableView and display just once cell with
        //  the latest message in it
    })
```

Comment: provide a full path of the messageRef the current path is for chat_messagesid child and your senderId is nested.you need to set full path.

Comment: I'm saving all messages under "chat_messagesid" only

Comment: while you are query data from firebase you need to provide a path to pointout that child

Comment: Will you please tell me in detail what path i have to provide

Comment: let messagesRef = Database.database().reference().child("chat_messagesid").child("GFYKf5..").child("b0jep..").child("-ks3..")